# Dynamic height of an item, can it be with CSS only?

Tags: html, css

the layout, if the user is not logged

```
LOGIN | news
BOX   | news
------| news
CHAT  | news
BOX   | news
CHAT  | news
BOX   | news
CHAT  | news
```

when logged:

```
CHAT  | news
BOX   | news
CHAT  | news
BOX   | news
CHAT  | news
BOX   | news
CHAT  | news
BOX   | news
```

somehow the "chatbox" must be as height as the "news box" at the right" and "login box" isnt seen if the user is logged in.

EDIT: the "news box" is fixed 400 pixel heighted.

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zo6vxcax/

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle or a pen?

Comment: updated, fiddle is added

Comment: My answer is your solution!!

Comment: No its not!! Yellow area isnt stretching'

Answer (score 0):

set an box around the login and chatbox area and give it those css:

```
.outer{
 height: 300px;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

like in the edited fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zo6vxcax/2/

Comment: not really. This is the jQuery solution but I dont want it... http://jsfiddle.net/zo6vxcax/1/

Comment: okay sorry, but then may the question should be with more infos

Comment: what do you use to not display the login box after login? php?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's your answer. [Live example on the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ronzm64/)

```js
$('#l').click (function() {
    $('#a1').toggle();
});
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
#a1
{
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
#b1
{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#c1
{
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: relative;     
    height: 300px;
}

.outer {
    background: black;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
 <div id="a1">login FIXED HEIGHT</div>
    <div id="b1">chatbox<br />chatbox<br /> MUST NOT EXCEED THE BOTTOM OF GREEN AREA and stretch until the bottom of green area</div>
</div>
<div id="c1">
    news<br />news<br />FIXED HEIGHT<input id="l" type="button" value="Toggle login box" />
</div>
```